# my project failed to run , saying "build failed"

Tags: java, android, build.gradle

I made a project that has lists of events and has a button which the user can set like an alarm or a reminder for the user.

i followed based on what i watched and it seems like there were no errors.

But when i tried to run my app, the error says

```
> Transform artifact materialdatetimepicker.aar (com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.3) with DexingNoClasspathTransform
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): int com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DateRangeLimiter.getMaxYear()","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}

> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'materialdatetimepicker.aar (com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.3)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-enable-desugaring=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=16}.
      > Execution failed for DexingNoClasspathTransform: C:\Users\Gerilla Family\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6dfb28f22b6828ae75d6c3c01e91a179\materialdatetimepicker-4.2.3\jars\classes.jar.
         > Error while dexing.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 52s
22 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 19 up-to-date
```

this is the build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.notifier"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jakebonk:NotifyMe:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.3'
}
```

Comment: please refer to this link-:
https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/issues/590

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot add on your **app/build.gradle**

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker#setup

Java

```
android {
 ...
 compileOptions {
   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 }
}
```

Kotlin

```
kotlinOptions {
  jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
}
```

Comment: i added that and it built well, but now im having a different error

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: The widget 'textview' is called before the activity/fragment is created. Be sure it is after setContentView on Activity and in the fragment, textview should be called inside onViewCreated function.

Comment: im still having the same error even i put it on the after of setContentView

Comment: Have you added the declaration of the textview on your activity? like; TextView text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txv_textviewid)

Comment: Yes i have added the declaration

Comment: This issue requires an extensive source code check, will you able to send a link of gists?

Comment: I found out that variable txtNotify is never included in activity_main.xml and the layout notify_popup.xml is never used.

Comment: The txtNotify is in the notify_popup.xml and i initialized it in the class MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

This library has minimum of supports only Android N.

```
implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:4.2.3'
```

Add this to build.gradle

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

Comment: i followed the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLngUva-Ves)
if i remove that dependency, what will be the alternative of this code?
`dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
                MainActivity.this,
                now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        );`